# Registrar datos de tablas anidadas con transaccion VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, transacciones

Mi problemática:

Tengo una base de datos y varias tablas relacionadas, dentro de un botón quiero agregar más de dos tablas al instante de forma anidada:

Explico: (En este ejemplo) tengo una tabla principal y una secundaria, están relacionadas, y lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

- Registrar datos en la tabla principal (tblPrincipal).
- Obtener el ID de registro de la tabla principal
- Registrar datos en la tabla secundario (tblSecundario) pasando como
  parametro el ID de la consulta anterior.

  ```
   _________________
  |   tblPrincipal  |
  |-----------------|
  | PK_id_principal |
  | nombre          |
  |_________________|

   _________________
  | tblSecundario   |
  |-----------------|
  | PK_id_secundario|
  | FK_id_principal |
  | descripcion     |
  |_________________|
  ```

He indagado por internet para saber la manera de hacerlo, y creo(si no es que estoy equivocado) que usando transacciones se puede lograr lo que pretendo. Anexo el código que he estructurado para este caso, pero no me funciona ya que me sale el error:

> Error al analizar la consulta. [Token line number = 1, Token line
>   offset = 53, Token in error = SELECT]

**Código**

```
Public Function fRegistrar(ByVal dts As vPrincipal)
        Try
            conectarbd()
            tra = con.BeginTransaction()
            cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tblPrincipal (nombre) VALUES (@nombre); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", dts.gstrNombre)
            cmd.Transaction = tra
            intID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar)

            cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tblSecundario (FK_id_principal, descripcion) VALUES (@FK_id, @desc)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_id", intID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", dts.gstrDescripcion)
            cmd.Transaction = tra

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
                Return True
                tra.Commit()
            Else
                Return False
                tra.Rollback()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            tra.Rollback()
            Return False
        Finally
            desconectarbd()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Es la primera vez que intento usar una transacción y no se si lo que estoy haciendo sea lo correcto. Espero me puedan orientar.

Para este ejemplo estoy usando una base de datos local, por eso uso `system.Data.SqlServerCe`

NOTA: Me preguntarán: porque no lo hago con procedimientos almacenados desde el servidor? No tengo acceso a los mismos, solo me crean las tablas, me facilitan los datos de acceso y ya. (Que no es la mejor manera, lo sé, pero ya es otro tema.)

Comment: Porque no intentas separar el insert y el scope_identity.

Comment: he separado colocando esto:     `cmd = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID", con)` pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error variando de **Token line offset = 53** a **Token line offset = 8**

Comment: Sql Server ce tiene identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de @gbianchi, estuve divagando por internet(más) y en efecto para SQL Server Compact Edition **NO** acepta `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ya que estuve mejorando mi código y al final me arrojaba el siguiente error:

> SQL Server Compact Edition no reconoce  la función. [Name of function
>   = SCOPE_IDENTITY, Data type (if known) = ]

De acuerdo a esta [REFERENCIA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916767/how-can-you-get-identity-or-scope-identity-to-work-in-sql-server-compact-edi) usé `@@IDENTITY` para lograr probar el uso de transacciones.

El código final que me ha funcionado:

```
Public Function fRegistrar(ByVal dts As vPrincipal)
        Try
            conectarbd()
            tra = con.BeginTransaction()
            cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tblPrincipal (nombre) VALUES (@nombre);", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", dts.gstrNombre)
            cmd.Transaction = tra
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID", con)
            cmd.Transaction = tra
            intID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar)

            cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tblSecundario (FK_id_primario, descripcion) VALUES (@FK_id, @desc)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_id", intID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", dts.gstrDescripcion)
            cmd.Transaction = tra
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            tra.Commit()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            tra.Rollback()
            Return False
        Finally
            desconectarbd()
        End Try
    End Function
```